# Поиск по фильтрам используя DQL

Tags: php, doctrine2

Добрый день.
Задача: отфильтровать всех пациентов по введённым в форму фильтрам.
В таблице patients есть одна запись с параметрами:

```
patient: {
  "name":"some name",
  "surname":"some surname",
}
```

Посылаем запрос на маршрут `GET api/patients?name=some name&surname=some surname`
Далее в методе (action) контроллера производим выборку

```
$dql="SELECT p FROM ".Patient::class." p  
        WHERE p.name LIKE :name 
         AND p.surname LIKE :surname";
$q = $this->_em->createQuery($dql);
$q->setParameter('name', array_get($params, 'name', '%%'));
$q->setParameter('surname', array_get($params, 'surname', '%%'));
return $q->getResult()
```

И всё работает. Но если например в форму не введён surname, то у нас получается такая конструкция `"WHERE p.name LIKE 'some name' AND p.surname LIKE '%%'"`
То есть `AND p.surname LIKE '%%'` вызывается напрасно. и мы напрасно отбираем производительность у запроса.
Так же если бы нам нужен был не `LIKE`а `Equels(=)`, то у нас вообще данная выборка бы ничего не возвращала так как при отсутствии surname мы бы получали строку запроса в виде: `"WHERE p.name = 'some name' AND p.surname =''"`.
Кончено  можно сделать свои инструменты для авто генерации `DQL WHERE`строки, но Это довольно распространённая задача. Неужели нет инструмента? Как люди делают подобные вещи в Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 0):

> свои инструменты для авто генерации DQL WHERE строки

[`query builder`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) у доктрины есть свой. А у репозитория есть метод `createQueryBuilder`, который вместо вас инициализирует шаги `select` и `from` для этого класса.

Что странно, генерирует `query builder` именно `DQL`, который затем при исполнении запроса парсится в абстрактное синтаксическое дерево, по которому строится нормальный `SQL`, вместо более логичного парсера `DQL` в машиночитаемый `query builder`, из которого напрямую генерировать `SQL`. Видимо, у кого-то много бесплатного `CPU`.